# Setting up environment for Hadoop datawarehousing (Hive)

Tags: hive, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I am new to Hadoop and trying to learn it on datawarehousing and analytical front.

Can someone advise me on how to set up my practice machines, especially with regards to
    1.Number of machines/nodes required to start learning
    2.Is it advisable to set up on Windows?
    3.What software needs to be installed 
    4.Availability of test/sample data

Also I would like to get advice on the best way to perform BI actions with Hive.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to download cloudera VM if you more interested in hadoop machinery. Another way to jump start immidiately - to use amazon EMR (elastic mapreduce). There is an option to create interactive hive cluster there and start playing with datasets stored in S3. 
Regarding number of nodes - it depends on goals. If you interested to "feel" some hadoop performance - try at least 4-6 nodes. 
Both ways listed above are good if you do not have access to organization's internal hadoop / hive cluster. And even in this case - I would suggest to try with them to gain some hands-on before using shared environment.